# Order of array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array. I want to change their order. Here is an array I want to use only array. I need to do this only using array.

```
    Array
    (
        [Abhijit Singh] => Array
            (
                [Physics] => Array
                    (


                        [Assignment] => Array
                            (
                                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                                [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                                [housename] => Aitchison
                                [RollNo] => 11556
                                [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                                [SubjectName] => Physics
                                [MarksObtained] => 10
                                [MaxMarks] => 100
                                [ExamType] => Assignment
                                [Grade] => 
                            )

                        [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                            (
                                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                                [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                                [housename] => Aitchison
                                [RollNo] => 11556
                                [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                                [SubjectName] => Physics
                                [MarksObtained] => 1
                                [MaxMarks] => 100
                                [ExamType] => Wednesday Tests
                                [Grade] => 
                            )

                        [Examinations] => Array
                            (
                                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                                [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                                [housename] => Aitchison
                                [RollNo] => 11556
                                [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                                [SubjectName] => Physics
                                [MarksObtained] => 100
                                [MaxMarks] => 100
                                [ExamType] => Examinations
                                [Grade] => 
                            )

                        [Projects] => Array
                            (
                                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                                [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                                [housename] => Aitchison
                                [RollNo] => 11556
                                [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                                [SubjectName] => Physics
                                [MarksObtained] => 10
                                [MaxMarks] => 100
                                [ExamType] => Projects
                                [Grade] => 
                            )

                    )

                [History] => Array
                    (
                        [Examinations] => Array
                            (
                                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                                [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                                [housename] => Aitchison
                                [RollNo] => 11556
                                [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                                [SubjectName] => History
                                [MarksObtained] => 20
                                [MaxMarks] => 100
                                [ExamType] => Examinations
                                [Grade] => 
                            )

                        [Projects] => Array
                            (
                                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                                [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                                [housename] => Aitchison
                                [RollNo] => 11556
                                [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                                [SubjectName] => History
                                [MarksObtained] => 20
                                [MaxMarks] => 100
                                [ExamType] => Projects
                                [Grade] => 
                            )

                        [Grades] => Array
                            (
                                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                                [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                                [housename] => Aitchison
                                [RollNo] => 11556
                                [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                                [SubjectName] => History
                                [MarksObtained] => 0
                                [MaxMarks] => 0
                                [ExamType] => Grades
                                [Grade] => 20
                            )



                    )

                [Hindi] => Array
                    (
                        [Projects] => Array
                            (


                [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Hindi
                            [MarksObtained] => 12
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Projects
                            [Grade] => 
                        )




                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Hindi
                            [MarksObtained] => 12
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Examinations
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                )

            [Econimics] => Array
                (
                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Econimics
                            [MarksObtained] => 2
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Wednesday Tests
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Econimics
                            [MarksObtained] => 20
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Examinations
                            [Grade] => 
                        )


                )

            [Chemsitry] => Array
                (
                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 0
                            [MaxMarks] => 0
                            [ExamType] => Grades
                            [Grade] => 20
                        )

                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 20
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Assignment
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 20
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Wednesday Tests
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 20
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Examinations
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Abhijit Singh
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Pawanjit Singh
                            [housename] => Aitchison
                            [RollNo] => 11556
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 20
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Projects
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                )

            [Geo] => Array
                (
                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [Grade] => NULL
                        )

                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                )

        )
 [Vaishali Bhalla] => Array
        (
            [Chemsitry] => Array
                (
                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Examinations
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Projects
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 0
                            [MaxMarks] => 0
                            [ExamType] => Grades
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Assignment
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Chemsitry
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Wednesday Tests
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                )

            [History] => Array
                (
                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => History
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Assignment
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => History
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Wednesday Tests
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => History
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Examinations
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => History
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Projects
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => History
                            [MarksObtained] => 0
                            [MaxMarks] => 0
                            [ExamType] => Grades
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                )

            [Physics] => Array
                (
                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Physics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Projects
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Physics
                            [MarksObtained] => 0
                            [MaxMarks] => 0
                            [ExamType] => Grades
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Physics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Assignment
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Physics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Wednesday Tests
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Physics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Examinations
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                )

            [Econimics] => Array
                (
                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Econimics
                            [MarksObtained] => 0
                            [MaxMarks] => 0
                            [ExamType] => Grades
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Econimics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Assignment
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Econimics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Wednesday Tests
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Econimics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Examinations
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [StudentName] => Vaishali Bhalla
                            [FatherName] => Mr. Atul Bhalla
                            [housename] => 
                            [RollNo] => 10794
                            [ExamMonth] => APRIL
                            [SubjectName] => Econimics
                            [MarksObtained] => 
                            [MaxMarks] => 100
                            [ExamType] => Projects
                            [Grade] => 
                        )

                )

            [Hindi] => Array
                (
                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [Grade] => NULL
                        )

                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                )

            [Geo] => Array
                (
                    [Grades] => Array
                        (
                            [Grade] => NULL
                        )

                    [Assignment] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Wednesday Tests] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Examinations] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                    [Projects] => Array
                        (
                            [MarksObtained] => NULL
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

The length  of this array may vary. Now, I want to rearrange the order of the subject name alphabetically in asc order.

Anybody have an idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    ksort($val);
    $temp[$key] = $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into objects, you are holding complicated data structures in arrays which provides hard to maintain and non-intuitive code.

Here is a tutorial on objects in php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

If you insist on arrays (and there is no good reason to do so) you can use php's built in sort function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

or

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php

depending on what exactly you with to accomplish.

Both these pages provide examples of use.

Comment: None of these references is particularly helpful to answer the OPs question.... should have been posted as a comment rather than an answer